# Corda Custom Notary tutorial issue

Tags: kotlin, corda

I've got a little problem with a part of Writing a custom notary service tutorial. The part shown on a screenshot is extracted directly from the tutorial and seems to be not working. Thanks in advance for any advice
[Problematic part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1AQxj.png)
Link to tutorial page: https://docs.corda.net/tutorial-custom-notary.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the following import:

```
import net.corda.core.utilities.unwrap
```